# How can i run a callback function after Backbone.history.loadUrl?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I tried the below code that does not work. Also i searched via google but find nothing. Backbone's official documentation does not have an entry about loadUrl.

```
app_router.on('route:page', function(id, name) {
    ...
});

app_router.on('route:file', function(id, name) {
      // first open the page
      Backbone.history.loadUrl("page", function() {
        // and open the file manager after page is loaded
      });
});
```

Comment: `yourRouterInstance.on("route", function(route){
 // alert('hello');
});`

Comment: i am trying to call loadUrl in another route `app_router.on('route:file', function(id, name) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass callback in loadUrl.

From annotated [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)

```
Attempt to load the current URL fragment. 
If a route succeeds with a match, returns true. 
If no defined routes matches the fragment, returns false.
```

And function definition

```
loadUrl: function(fragment)
```

Instead use

```
 router.on("route", function() {
   ...
 });
```

To answer your edited question, you can do something like

```
 app_router.on('route:file', function(id, name) {
    // first open the page
    if(Backbone.history.loadUrl("page")){
       // and open the file manager after page is loaded
    });
 });
```

Comment: I just updated the question. Please look again. I have to run loadUrl in another route. Before loading the file manager, i have to be shore the page is loaded. Otherwise my code will be broken.

Comment: Maybe i can merge two route, i don't know.